# MFC Controls are getting disappeared after scrolling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I am working on  dialog based MFC application in WinCE.
I created few controls in a dialog and scrolled down.
When i scroll up again, the controls in the first screen got disappeared.

Controls getting created in OnInitDialog() like below at coordinates (50,10)

```
test->Create(_T("Title"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, CRect(50,10,200,40), this, ID_TITLE);
```

Scroll handling i am doing in OnVScroll() like below

```
 switch(nSBCode)
 {
  case SB_LINEDOWN:
  {
   if(nPos < max)
   {
    ScrollWindowEx(0, SCROLLDOWN_LINE_STEPSIZE, CRect(0,0, rect.right - 25, rect.bottom), NULL, NULL, NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE); 
    pScrollBar->SetScrollPos(nPos - SCROLLDOWN_LINE_STEPSIZE); //nPos+10
   }
   break;
  }
  case SB_LINEUP:
  {
   if(nPos > min)
   {
    ScrollWindowEx(0, SCROLLUP_LINE_STEPSIZE, CRect(0,0, rect.right - 25, rect.bottom), NULL, NULL, NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE); 
    pScrollBar->SetScrollPos(nPos - SCROLLUP_LINE_STEPSIZE); //Ex: nPos-10
   }
   break;
  }

 default:
  printf("Notimplemented");
  break;
 }
```

I am handling Scroll down and scroll up.
While scrolling down, all the controls in Dialog are shown.
But while scrolling up, the controls at the top got disappeared.

What's going on ?
Should i implement OnPaint() method for drawing the controls each time i scroll ?
If so, how ?

Comment: are you doing any moving / resizing of those controls? Maybe you're calculating bounds incorrectly somewhere? Do they still function or are they gone entirely? Do they partially disappear if you scroll down a little bit, or is it always the entire control?

Comment: There is no minimize button in My WinCE emulator. Am using Windows mobile 6.x SDK with visual studio 2008

Comment: @tenfour: Always entire control is disappearing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controls disappear after scrolling in Cwnd with ScrollWindowEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154470/controls-disappear-after-scrolling-in-cwnd-with-scrollwindowex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code that works fine. I hope it will help you.

```
LRESULT CMyWindow::OnVScroll( UINT code, UINT position )
{
    SCROLLINFO info = { sizeof( SCROLLINFO ), SIF_ALL };
    GetScrollInfo( m_wnd, SB_VERT, &info );
    int previous_pos = info.nPos;
    switch( code )
    {
    case SB_TOP:
        info.nPos = 0;
        break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        info.nPos = info.nMax - info.nPage;
        break;
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        info.nPos = min( info.nPos + 1, info.nMax - (int)info.nPage );
        break;
    case SB_LINEUP:
        info.nPos = max( info.nPos - 1, info.nMin );
        break;
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
        info.nPos = min( info.nPos + (int)info.nPage, info.nMax - (int)info.nPage );
        break;
    case SB_PAGEUP:
        info.nPos = max( info.nPos - (int)info.nPage, info.nMin );
        break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
        info.nPos = position;
        break;
    }
    int offset = previous_pos - info.nPos;
    if( offset != 0 )
    {
        ScrollWindowEx( m_wnd, 0, offset, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE );
        SetScrollPos( m_wnd, SB_VERT, info.nPos, FALSE );
    }
    return 0L;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. It will expose the same issue you set out to solve: Child windows will disappear. This is spelled out in the documentation of [CWnd::ScrollWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwbfte93.aspx): *"If the SW_SCROLLCHILDREN flag is specified, Windows will not properly update the screen if part of a child window is scrolled."* The solution is to manually move the child windows calling [DeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms632681).

Comment: @IInspectable That will only happen when **part** of a child window is scrolled. Since I am passing `NULL` for the `lpRectScroll` parameter the entire child will scroll.

Comment: I don't see anything in your answer that ensures, that child windows will not get moved partially out of the client area, and consequently partially moved in later. Child windows can be positioned outside the client area. The effect is, that they become (partially) invisible. Your code does not guard against this.

Answer (score 1):

From the ScrollWindowEx docs:

> dy
>  Specifies the amount, in
>   device units, of vertical scrolling.
>   This parameter must be **a negative
>   value** to scroll up.

I bolded the relevant phrase.

Comment: Yes, i am using a negative value only for scroll down. Sorry i didn't show the macro values in code.