# Controls disappear after scrolling in Cwnd with ScrollWindowEx

Tags: c++, mfc

I've implemented a CScrollBar in a Cwnd, but after scroll the controls on the window disappear. I've heard I could use DeferWindowPos someway, but I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

```
CPanel::CPanel()
{
    CreateEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, _T("Static"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER, m_clRect, pwndParent, IDC_PANEL_FORM);
    ScrollBarInit();    
}
```

Creating scrollbar

```
void CPanel::ScrollBarInit()
{

    //Before this i calculate size of scrollbar and size of scrollarea
    m_pclScrollBar = new CScrollBar();
    m_pclScrollBar->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_VERT | SBS_RIGHTALIGN, clRectScrollbar, this, IDC_SCROLLBAR_FORM);
    m_pclScrollBar->SetScrollRange(VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN, VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX);
    //After this I add scrollbar info

}
```

Handle message

```
void CPanel::OnVScroll(UINT iSBCode, UINT iPos, CScrollBar* pclScrollBar)
    {
        switch(pclScrollBar->GetDlgCtrlID())
        {
            case IDC_SCROLLBAR_FORM:
                ScrollBarScroll(iSBCode, iPos, pclScrollBar);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Scroll

```
void CPanel::ScrollBarScroll(UINT iSBCode, UINT iPos, CScrollBar *pclScrollBar)
    {
        int     iScrollPositionPrevious;
        int     iScrollPosition;
        int     iScrollPositionOriginal;

        iScrollPositionOriginal = m_pclScrollBar->GetScrollPos();
        iScrollPosition = iScrollPositionOriginal;

        if(m_pclScrollBar != NULL)
        {
            SCROLLINFO info = {sizeof( SCROLLINFO ), SIF_ALL};
            pclScrollBar->GetScrollInfo(&info, SB_CTL);

            pclScrollBar->GetScrollRange(&info.nMin, &info.nMax);
            info.nPos = pclScrollBar->GetScrollPos();

            iScrollPositionPrevious = info.nPos;

            switch(iSBCode)
            {
                case SB_TOP:            // Scroll to top
                    iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN;
                    break;

                case SB_BOTTOM:         // Scroll to bottom
                    iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX;
                    break;

                case SB_ENDSCROLL:      // End scroll
                    break;

                case SB_LINEUP:         // Scroll one line up
                    if(iScrollPosition - VSCROLL_LINE >= VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN)
                        iScrollPosition -= VSCROLL_LINE;
                    else
                        iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN;
                    break;

                case SB_LINEDOWN:       // Scroll one line down
                    if(iScrollPosition + VSCROLL_LINE <= VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX)
                        iScrollPosition += VSCROLL_LINE;
                    else
                        iScrollPosition = VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX;
                    break;

                case SB_PAGEUP:         // Scroll one page up
                {
                    // Get the page size
                    SCROLLINFO   scrollInfo;
                    m_pclScrollBar->GetScrollInfo(&scrollInfo, SIF_ALL);

                    if(iScrollPosition > VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN)
                        iScrollPosition = max(VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN, iScrollPosition - VSCROLL_PAGE);
                    break;
                }

                case SB_PAGEDOWN:       // Scroll one page down
                {
                    // Get the page size
                    SCROLLINFO   scrollInfo;
                    m_pclScrollBar->GetScrollInfo(&scrollInfo, SIF_ALL);

                    if(iScrollPosition < VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX)
                        iScrollPosition = min(VSCROLL_RANGE_MAX, iScrollPosition + VSCROLL_PAGE);
                    break;
                }

                case SB_THUMBPOSITION:  // Scroll to the absolute position. The current position is provided in nPos
                case SB_THUMBTRACK:     // Drag scroll box to specified position. The current position is provided in nPos
                    iScrollPosition = iPos;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if(iScrollPositionOriginal != iScrollPosition)
            {
               m_pclScrollBar->SetScrollPos(iScrollPosition);

               CRect clientArea;
               GetClientRect(clientArea);

               CRect scrollbarArea;
               m_pclScrollBar->GetWindowRect(scrollbarArea);

               CRect scrollArea(clientArea);
               scrollArea.DeflateRect(0, 0, scrollbarArea.Width(), 0);
               ScrollWindowEx(0, iScrollPositionOriginal - iScrollPosition, scrollArea, NULL,
                       NULL, NULL, SW_SCROLLCHILDREN | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear - what is the problem? If some controls are positioned in the form at its current scroll position, they will likely move out of view when you scroll your window...

Comment: @VladFeinstein Yes of course :D But they won't come back when scrolling back.

Comment: If you trace `iScrollPositionOriginal` and `iScrollPosition` to the Output window, are their value what you expect? I mean, do you really come BACK to the original position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving child windows using [CWnd::ScrollWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwbfte93.aspx) using the `SW_SCROLLCHILDREN` flag is problematic:

> If the [SW_SCROLLCHILDREN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb787593) flag is specified, Windows will not properly update the screen if part of a child window is scrolled. The part of the scrolled child window that lies outside the source rectangle will not be erased and will not be redrawn properly in its new destination. Use the [DeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms632681) Windows function to move child windows that do not lie completely within the lpRectScroll rectangle.

The solution is to move child windows manually. [DeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms632681) has the same effect as calling [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) for multiple windows, but is optimized to perform the layout in a single call. This helps reduce visual artifacts, where controls appear to move relative to each other, until everything is settled.

`DeferWindowPos` requires a structure holding the new window properties. It is created calling [BeginDeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632672), then updated for each window with a call to `DeferWindowPos`, and finally sent off to the system to perform the repositioning with [EndDeferWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633440). The following code assumes an array containing `CWnd*`s of all child controls in an array, with *cx* and *cy* holding the horizontal and vertical offset. It is meant to replace the call to `ScrollWindowEx`:

```
CWnd* controls[] = { m_pEdit, m_pButton, ... };

HDWP hDwp = ::BeginDeferWindowPos( ARRAYSIZE( controls ) );

for ( size_t index = 0; index < ARRAYSIZE( controls ); ++index ) {
    // Find the current window position
    CRect wndRect;
    controls[index]->GetWindowRect( wndRect );
    // DeferWindowPos requires client coordinates, so we need to convert from screen coords
    ScreenToClient( wndRect );
    // Set the control's new position
    hDwp = ::DeferWindowPos( hDwp, *controls[index], NULL,
                             wndRect.left + cx, wndRect.top + cy, 0, 0,
                             SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE |
                             SWP_NOZORDER );
}

// All new control positions have been recorded. Now perform the operation
::EndDeferWindowPos( hDwp );
```

Comment: This looks promising, except that I dont have `cx` and `cy`. But I guess I can create them on top and give them the value in each case like dx = VSCROLL_RANGE_MIN ets

Comment: @JohanMagnusson: cx is 0, since you only scroll vertically. cy is `iScrollPosition - iScrollPositionOriginal`, just like in the call to `ScrollWindowEx`.